# How to XOR a QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt

How would I XOR a QByteArray in C++? I am trying to decrypt a json file that had been XOR encrypted by a python script so I can load it as a QJsonDocument

**Update**

```
def encrypt(input):
    key = ['K', 'C', 'Q']
    output = []

    for i in range(len(input)):
        xor_num = ord(input[i]) ^ ord(key[i % len(key)])
        output.append(chr(xor_num))

    return ''.join(output)
```

and here is what I have so far in my c++ code for xor the QByteArray:

```
QByteArray arr = file.readAll();
char key[3] = {'K', 'C', 'Q'};
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];
```

Comment: You need to loop through every element and apply the xor to each element of your `QByteArray`. This should be easy. The example for operator[](int) could be used as a starting point: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#operator-5b-5d

Comment: Do you have the python script that encrypts the data? If so maybe you should edit your question and add that.

Comment: Okay! That's what I was thinking of doing but I am new to Qt so I was a little lost. I updated with the python code though

Comment: I do not know the use case, but why not using a proper encryption method which is supported by Qt and some python library?

Comment: Is there an encryption method supported by both?

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is *defined* to be 1 in C++ (and C), so using it in your formula is unnecessary and needlessly confuses things.

Comment: So what is the problem with the code in the question now?

Comment: It still doesn't properly decrypt the json file. When it is used in my application, it doesn't work

Comment: Well, at the very least, show example encrypted data (in hex because you're dealing with bits, see `QByteArray::toHex()` for convenience), expected output and actual output (also in hex). [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice, of course.

Comment: So I got it working on my mac build but for some reason it is crashing on windows. The code is the same. The data is the same. I just don't know why

Comment: @drescherjm that method is very slow. xoring 1mb qbytearray that way takes me around 150 ms. For hand-made byte array (unsigned char array) it takes less than 10 ms (both ran on same potato PC). Im using it for entropy boosting, in my code so I would love to have fast way on QByteArray.

Comment: Are you timing an optimized / Release build?